# I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of parenthesis in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Simply I cannot figure out how to get rid of one stupid parenthesis on this list in scheme.
Here is the list:

```
(("R" 100 199 (("L" 120 140 160 180))) ("R" 200 299 (("L" 220 240 260 280))))
```

I know I have to use car and cdr but I feel like I have used every possibility.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Which one are you hoping to get rid of? Usually a product of `(cons (cons somethng ...))` that should have been `(cons something ...)` instead.

Comment: I’m just trying to get the very first parentheses off so it still says (R 100 199...etc)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of the top-level parenthesis because they are binding two expressions together, as you can see by splitting the expression in different lines:

```
(
 ("R" 100 199 (("L" 120 140 160 180)))
 ("R" 200 299 (("L" 220 240 260 280)))
)
```

The only parenthesis that may be redundant here are the ones around the "L" expressions.

```
(
 ("R" 100 199 ("L" 120 140 160 180))
 ("R" 200 299 ("L" 220 240 260 280))
)
```

But these expressions look "unbalanced". As a wild guess, I would think this is what you're looking for (now, using proper Scheme indentation):

```
(("R" 100 199)
 ("L" 120 140 160 180)
 ("R" 200 299)
 ("L" 220 240 260 280))
```

But to know for sure, we would have to know what exactly you're trying to do, and what these "L" and "R" mean.